# HowTo fetch data to viewmodel the quickest way

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel

I have a simple problem with my site.
Inside my site, I'm using two different models, with some identical named fields.
Because of collision, I have to give them unique names and for not loosing the modelbinding, I decided to use viewModels.

So I have a Model like this:

```
namespace MySite.Models
{
  public class Function : BaseEntity
  {
    //Beziehung zur Funktionsgruppe
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Übergeordnete Funktion")]
    public int FunctionGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual FunctionGroup FunctionGroup { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Bezeichnung")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
}
```

And I have a new ViewModel like this:

```
namespace MySite.ViewModels
{
  public class FunctionViewModel
  {
    //Properties of BaseEntity
    public int F_Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Erstellt")]
    public string F_Created { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Bearbeitet")]
    public string F_LastChange { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Bearbeiter")]
    public string F_ByUser { get; set; }

    //Beziehung zur Funktionsgruppe
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Übergeordnete Funktion")]
    public int F_FunctionGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual FunctionGroup F_FunctionGroup { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Bezeichnung")]
    public string F_Name { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Now my Question is, is there a way to automatically fetch the data of the corresponding model, while loading the ViewModel?

Something like a kind of function directly inside the `{ get; set; }`?
Actually I load field by field form the model into the ViewModel.

Hope that I could have described Right, what I'd like to do.

Carsten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Automapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/) for mapping or getting your data from Model to ViewModel or vice-versa. It will be hard for you to map/configure if your name of your property is different so have the same name in view model as well. (If possible)

Comment: As I wrote above, I Need the different fields. That's the reason, why I use ViewModels.

Comment: yes you can keep different fields no issues with that. still you can use Automapper to map your details from Model to ViewModel or vice-versa.

Comment: does someone know a tuitorial for actual version of automapper?
I'm too stupid to understand their pages and all tuts I found where outdated.

Comment: check these articles so you can get idea about how to work with Automapper 
  --- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639618/CRUD-Opearations-using-AutoMapper-in-an-MVC-Applic   and https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-automapper-in-mvc-project/

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Ok, it seems, that both sites where written before actual Version of AM.
The actual Approach seems to be very different. :(

Comment: Try this one step by step https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html